# Logging with Catel. Get Type of Log

Tags: catel

In my project I use the logging from catel. I add my own LogListener.

```
LogManager.AddListener(_myloglistener)
```

I catch the event from `_logListener.LogMessage` and want to display the log messages in my view.

Now my question: Where do I get the information of the `LogType`.

Is it a info, warning or an error. I do not find any property in the `LogMessageEventArgs`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LogMessageEventArgs.LogEvent` property.

Another tip, take a look at these projects:

1. [Orc.Controls => LogViewer](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.Controls/tree/develop/src/Orc.Controls/Orc.Controls.Shared/Controls/LogViewer) (simple log viewer control)
2. [Orc.LogViewer](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.LogViewer) (advanced log viewer with filtering, etc).

[image: Orc.LogViewer]

Comment: Hi Geert.Thanks for the answer. The controls looks nice. But I have to create my own control to have our Corporate Design.

Comment: Then take a look at it, that's the whole point of the answer ;-)

Comment: Yes I know you can customize it. But I need only a simple logwindow for the machine. And I think its easier to create my own simple view instead of customize this control.

Comment: And I think I have found a little bug in AdvancedLogViewerViewModel.cs
Maybe thats the wrong place here to report, but...

The Property Level RaisepropertyChanged before value is changed

Comment: I mean: if you ever need info on how to do something, you can look at it as an example ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the report, will change it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But maybe one more question. Why has LogEvent Flags. A log event can have only one level. Or not?

Comment: That's a legit question. However, this way we can combine states when filtering.

Comment: Ok. But this this is error prone. Better a enum without flag and for filter use a list of this enums.